# How to give limited access to S3 resource to a user of an app?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Every user has unique data that is saved in S3. This resource should be only be visible to that specific user. Traditional way is to fetch this stuff on the backend and pass it along to the user. Making sure in application logic that only stuff that user is qualified for gets it. However, Why pass this extra data through my app when I can just give the key/token to that the user I want to be able to access the S3 bucket. So they can retrieve data from it and save to it.

Comment: This question doesn't warrant a close vote... why would someone think this question doesn't have focus?  It's probably the most focused question I've read all night...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Traditional way is to fetch this stuff on the backend and pass it along to the user.

No, it isn't.  Nobody should be doing this.

> However, Why pass this extra data through my app when I can just give the key/token to that the user...

You're going the right direction here.  Fortunately, S3 defines a better way, which *is* the usual method as well.

Rather than giving a key, you cryptographically sign a URL.  The key/secret stay server-side and hidden from the end user.  You create a URL that indicates what resource is to be downloaded, as well as other parameters such as an expiration date for that URL.  Then, you "sign" it using a computed value that only someone with the key/secret could calculate.  The resulting URL can be given directly to your client via API response or whatever method you want.

The client then requests the resource with this URL, and it's served directly from S3.  S3 verifies the signature, knows that it came from you, and serves up the appropriate response.

An example, assuming you're using the S3 JS SDK:

```
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Key: 'path/to/object'
});
```

See also:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't explain much about how you intend the application to work, so here's some general advice...

Yes, you can create **temporary credentials** using Amazon Cognito and the AWS Security Token Service. These credentials will have associated permissions that determine what they can access. This is quite common with **mobile apps**, since they can simply call the AWS API and request data directly.

[Using Amazon Cognito for Mobile Apps - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html)

You can also use AWS STS directly (without Cognito), if your app manages its own authentication.

The important part is to only provide permissions to the data they are entitled to access. For that, you might consider using [IAM Policy Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html), with each user having their own folder in a shared Amazon S3 bucket.